# make css sheet apply over a "after page loaded" html element in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, dynamic

I have a div in my page which I create with javscript when the mouse is over a specific area of the page(like a tool tip).
The thing is that my css sheet has no effect over this div I create, to which I also set its id. is there a way to make my css sheet apply over that div? Thanks..
Code:

```
// mouseover event calls:
function showMyToolTip(mouseXPosition, mouseYposition){ 
  // if mosue over object loacated at objLocationX, objLocationY
  if (mouseXPosition == objLocationX&& mouseYPosition == objLocationY){
     var div = document.createElement("div");
     div.setAttribute("id", "divMouseOverObj"); 
     document.appendChild(div);
  }
}
```

---

css sheet:
    div#divMouseOverObj{
      width: 100px;
      color: green;
    }

Comment: What if you use just the id? `#divMouseOverObj { ... }`

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe you could create a function with the code to load the stylesheet, and call the function as soon as the window loads (add the following line to the end of a script tag inside the head element): `window.addEventListener( "load", functionName, false );`)

Comment: GolezTrol, what you suggest works. removed the div in the sytesheet : div#divMouseOverObj!!!
thank you boths

Answer (score 0):

Question asked by GolezTrol solved the issue for me.Thanks
 change in css sheet:
    divMouseOverObj{ 
      width: 100px; 
      color: green; 
    }